# Get Current User's Role in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute() function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC 4 web application. 
I need to know if there is a way to find the role of the currently logged in user in the `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()` function (present in Global.asax).
I used to use `Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")` function to know if the user belongs to Admin role or not, but for some reason this function and `User.IsInRole("Admin")` function do not seam to work.
The above mentioned two functions are giving the following error:
***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)***

I tried searching for a solution but failed to find one. If someone has any idea and can guide me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Does it change anything if you try cacheRolesInCookie=true in RoleManager configuration of web.config

Comment: do you have custom principal?

Comment: @jbl i'll try that out.

Comment: @maxlego no, don't have any custom principal.

Comment: can you copy the stacktrace